# How to handle invalid bearer tokens

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, bearer-token

I have an `ASP.NET MVC` website and a `Web API 2` project.

I use a bearer token that I store in the identity claims to identify a user on the API.

It works but I noticed that when I use a different server for the API, all the tokens are invalid.

I'm confused about what to do when a token is invalid (because it's a different server or because it's expired).

How are we supposed to handle that?

For the expired token, I guess I could store the expiration date and ask for a new token or implement the [OAuth2 Refresh Tokens](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/). But for the other scenario, I don't know what to do.

Thank you

Comment: The `machinekey` is used for the encryption/decryption, so if they are different between the servers, when decrypting the token, it will not match. So just make sure the machinekey values are the same in both servers.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought. So what should I do when I change server?

Comment: If I use Azure or any cloud hosting, will the machinekey change often?

Comment: If you use the same cloud service the machine key is synced between the different instances. So there's no problem on Azure related to this. I don't know exactly when the machine key will change on Azure, but if you stay in the same deployment without tearing down the whole service it should remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have different server for the API, you have to be sure that **all WebConfig files have the same machineKey tag**. In case of Windows Azure you can change the web.config file deployed.

```
<system.web>
...
<machineKey validationKey="57B449BBA8F9E656087FF7848727E122C5F5966F65AC0FC25FB3532193B59CFCD13B370883FFC184C1F1500638F33E6F67B37CAED1D9BC65BBC6CFFB232BFD0B" decryptionKey="6D9FBE88D16B3FA5B5E6B37460BBE50DA85D5B4C482159006B5A337C58AA9E79" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
...
</system.web>
```

Use this [machine Key Generator](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey). Token is created based on the machineKey, so you have to be sure that this field is identical. If not, the token created on one project will not be valid for the other.